# Offsetting the difference between measured and expected data

Tags: math, microcontroller, sensors, data-analysis

I am testing a temperature sensor for a project. i found that there exist a variance between the expected and measured value. As the difference is non -linear over e temperature range i cant simply add an offset . Is there a way i can do a kind of offset to the acquired data ?

**UPDATE**
I have a commercial heater element which heat up to a set temperature(i named this temperature as expected). On the other side i have a temp sensor (my proj)which measure the temperature of the heater (here i named it as measured).

I noticed the difference between the measured and expected which i would like to compensate so that measured will be close to the expected value.

Example 
If my sensor measured 73.3 it should be process by some means(mathematically or otherwise)so that it will show that it is close to 70.25.

Hope this clears thing a little.

```
Measured    Expected
30.5    30.15
41.4    40.29
52.2    50.31
62.8    60.79
73.3    70.28
83      79.7
94      90.39
104.3   99.97
114.8   109.81
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you trying to do this for a specific, single sensor or are you expecting to correct readings from many sensors of the same type? Is this a one-time fix or is it for a product? What level of accuracy do you need in the final readings?

Comment: Yes, could you provide a bit more detail as to what you wish to accomplish, maybe provide a simple example of the desired result based on made-up data?

Comment: @sean Is this correct to infer you have some logic (function) to calculate Expected? You want to make it better approximation to data actually observed, right?

Comment: @JoeHass For now is only for a single sensor but i will be interested in a method which will work for all similar sensor as i believe most sensor will have some inherent error. Thanks

Comment: @lizusek Yes thats what i meant i have updated my question to show my details. Thanks

Comment: @sean then my answer might be of help to you

Comment: please ask if something is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are interested in describing deviation one variable from the other. What you are looking for is function

```
g( x) = f( x) - x
```

which returns approximation, a prediction, what number to add to **x** to get **y** data based on real **x** input. You need the prediction of **y** based on observed **x** values first, the **f(x)**. This is what you can get from doing a regression:

```
x = MeasuredExpected ( what you have estimated, and I assume 
                                        you will know this value)
y = MeasuredReal ( what have been actually observed instead of x)

f( x) = MeasuredReal( estimated) = alfa*x + beta + e
```

In the simplest case of just one variable **you don't even have to include special tools** for this. The coefficients of equation are equal to:

```
alfa = covariance( MeasuredExpected, MeasuredReal) / variance( MeasuredExpected)
beta = average( MeasuredReal) - alfa * average( MeasuredExpected)
```

so for each expected measured **x** you can now state that the most probable value of real measured is:

```
f( x) = MeasuredReal( expected) = alfa*x + beta  (under assumption that error
                                                 is normally distributed, iid)
```

So you have to add

```
g( x) = f( x) - x = ( alfa -1)*x + beta
```

to account for the difference that you have observed between your usual Expected and Measured.

Comment: While I agree with you on how to quantify the deviation, I'm not sure that's what the OP wants. If I follow you right, you need to have a one-on-one match on measured/expected values, which allows you to compute the deviation. What I understood is that the OP wishes to estimate the deviation rule and apply it to the measured values to get them closer to what is expected. My proposition was to use a regression to estimate the deviation rule based on sample measure/expectation couples.

Comment: no, this is not correct. I also suggest regression to account for an error present in Expected. This should be add to Expected to get best approximation of Measured

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean he wants to use this experience to estimate real (read measurement) values from the expected values?

Comment: yes, from what OP presents I infer he has some logic (function) already to calculate Expected and now OP wants to make it better approximation to data actually observed

Comment: @lizusek Correct me if i am wrong . Eventually I have no means to calculate expected temperature. The sensor will be stand alone that works like a thermometer and it have to account for the offset.

Comment: what you have is some data which you think will be observed, call it x. But actually observed is y. correct? You can then create f(x) = y(x) and use this to get y corresponding to x. Is this what you need? If not, please be more specific.

Comment: Yes. Thats what i need . Infering from your answer i found this http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/models/CalibrationCurve.html . This ouputs something like y = 1.0476x - 0.3816 which is similar to your answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes. 1.0476 = alfa,  - 0.3816 = beta

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a data sample in order to do a regression analysis on the variation and use the regression function as an offset function.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

Comment: Hi , is there any tools that is free with this function ?

Comment: You should look for statistics and numerical analysis, data mining software like R for instance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29 Of course, this method works if the variation follows some kind of rule (even if not linear), otherwise it will probably be hard to find a suitable regression.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calibration [lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) (LUT).

The error in the sensor reading is not linear over the entire range of the sensor, but you can divide the range up into a number of sub-ranges for which the error within the sub-range is nearly linear.  Then you calibrate the sensor by taking a reading in each sub-range and calculating the offset error for each sub-range.  Store the offset for each sub-range in an array to create a calibration lookup table.

Once the calibration table is known, you can correct a measurement by performing a table lookup for the proper offset.  Use the actual measured value to determine the index into the array from which to get the proper offset.

The sub-ranges don't need to be same-sized although that should make it easy to calculate the proper table index for any measurement.  (If the sub-ranges are not same-sized then you could use a multidimensional array (matrix) and store not only the offset but also the beginning or end point of each sub-range.  Then you would scan through the begin-points to determine the proper table index for any measurement.)

You can make the correction more accurate by dividing into smaller sub-ranges and creating a larger calibration lookup table.  Or you may be able to interpolate between two table entries to get a more accurate offset.